# Jest, test an output string

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've just started using jest, but some things are not clear to me.

For Example, why if a test this function:

```
const liElement = object => `<li>${object.title}</li>`;
```

with:

```
expect(liElement({title: 'example'}).toBe('<li>example</li>'));
```

Why my test fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`expect().toEqual()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#toequalvalue) instead of the [strict identity check `expect().toBe()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobevalue).

```
expect(liElement({title: 'example'})).toEqual('<li>example</li>');
```